# Proper use of alike

Tags: difference

Are the following two sentences grammatical?

He is **indifferent alike** to praise and blames.

He is **indifferent** to praise and blames **alike**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion over the position of an adverb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/confusion-over-the-position-of-an-adverb)

Comment: "praise and blame" not "blames"

Comment: alike has to go at the end of the two grouped items.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the two answers so far. In my opinion both sentences are grammatical and understandable.

I might however be tempted to place a comma in the first, i.e.

*He is indifferent alike, to praise and blame.*

The comma here indicates a very slight pause.

Comment: Maybe if you are speaking, for the comma thing. But then, alike is not really a spoken language word.

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is ungrammatical.

Lexico says about *one* meaning of the word [**alike**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/alike)

> ADVERB
>   **1.1** Used to show that something applies equally to a number of specified subjects.
>   *he talked in a friendly manner to staff and patients alike*

The second sentence is better, but **blame** is the same kind of word as **praise**. They *can* be used in the plural, for example "[sing your praises](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sing-someone-s-something-s-praises)", but the sentence should be

> He is indifferent to praise and blame alike.

Comment: The issue of using *blame* instead of *blames* aside, your provided definition of the word *alike* does nothing to say that it can't be used in a different location. The location of adverbs can frequently be changed without making the sentence ungrammatical. While I would say the location of *alike* in the first sentence isn't common, I certainly wouldn't say that it's ungrammatical.

Answer (score -1):

> Q. Are the following two sentences grammatical?
>
> - He is indifferent alike to praise and blames <-**No**
> - He is indifferent to praise and blame<s>s</s> alike <-**Yes**, but no need to pluralise 'blame'.

"Alike" in this context means *the same* or *equally*. You could instead say:

- He is **equally** indifferent to praise and blame.

or

- He is **as** indifferent to praise as he is to blame.