# Positions of an adverb "quickly"

Tags: adverbs, word-order

My question has occured after I read [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/confusion-over-the-position-of-an-adverb) "Confusion over the position of an adverb."

Ian R answers
(1) I can **run quickly** to the store **,** and
(2) I can **quickly run** to the store **!**
have different meanings.

I understand this as "quickly" changes its meaning depending on its positions.  Then, can I say like these?

> 1."You cannot quickly run to any stores now because it started snowing."

> 2."You cannot quickly run to a store."(variation where  the explanation of the situation is ommited)

I am not sure if I can put "quickly" before a verb in cases where the subject is not I.
Thank you!

Comment: Nope, the meaning is the same. quickly run and run quickly in the sense of go to the store and buy something are the same thing. However, in AmE, we'd probably say: I'm going to make a quick run to the store. (And the Brits might say: pop out to the shop) [laughs] Also, your negative sentences there sounds very odd to a native ear. "You can't make a quick run to the store because of all the snow". Finally, cannot sounds awkward there. We just use "can't" in speech.

Comment: I agree with Ian R. except that I would understand (2) to mean that the whole errand will only take a short time. This isn't about _quickly_ having two meanings, though - just that the two versions of the sentence could have a slight difference in emphasis.

Comment: @Lambie  Thank you very much for your information, I understand!

Comment: @KateBunting  I see! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I say this?

Yes. Those sentences are not strictly prohibited. They are grammatical.

However as mentioned in the comments, "cannot" sounds awkward. Overall, "you can't make a quick run to the store because of all the snow" would be more idiomatic.

Actually, I'd recommend omitting "quickly". "You can't go to the store now, it's snowing too much."

The reason they can't go is because of the snow.  At that point, it's irrelevant if the trip is fast, slow, or normal. All excursions are impeded.  It sounds like you are sarcastically making fun of the speaker by repeating back to them verbatim "you can't *quickly* go to the store."